# Quantidade de atributos em uma classe em Python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Existe alguma "regra"/convenção para a quantidade de atributos em uma classe?

Exemplo: Em um jogo, um Personagem(classe) tem mais de 30 atributos entre nome, nivel, força, etc.

Com todos os atributos encapsulados a classe acaba ficando gigantesca. Isso é normal ou é uma má prática?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A regra que impera é o bom senso**, e principalmente, as [boas práticas de programação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_coding_practices).

> A **orientação objeto** é uma forma de programação que habilita desenvolvedores a pensarem nas coisas como as que trabalham na vida real: objetos. <sup>[2](https://medium.com/from-the-scratch/oop-everything-you-need-to-know-about-object-oriented-programming-aee3c18e281b)</sup>

Com técnicas como [composição](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composi%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_objetos), [herança](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heran%C3%A7a_(inform%C3%A1tica)) e [polimorfismo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polimorfismo), pode-se alcançar uma melhor [abstração](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_principle_(computer_programming)):

```
class Armamento:
   dano = 1
...
class Punhal(Armamento):
    def apunhalar() 
...
class Rifle(Armamento) 
    def atirar()
...
class Agente:
    nivel = 10
    forca = 2
    arma = Rifle
...
class Personagem(Agente): 
    nome = 'ficticio'
    def aguardar_entrada()
...
class Inimigo(Agente):
    def cacular_ataque() 
...
```

A falta dessa abstração, deverá acarretar em maior esforço/custo operacional para compreensão e [manutenção](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manutenibilidade) do código, afetando a [qualidade do software](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualidade_de_software).

Ainda que seja exagerado, digo que **sim, é uma má prática uma classe com mais de 30 atributos**, com muitas exceções. <sup>[9](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125357/keep-my-classes-and-methods-as-small-as-possible)</sup>

Busque na [orientação objeto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_a_objetos), ou [no necessário para sua aplicação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigma_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o), seu caminho.

Comment: Excelente compreensão da minha questão e objetividade na resposta. Parabéns e obrigado!